# XXXKotlinCharCompanion could not be mapped to KotlinChar.Companion

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I encounter a build error when I build my project in [Kotlin Mobile Multiplatform](https://www.jetbrains.com/kotlin-multiplatform/) : `'XXXKotlinCharCompanion' could not be mapped to 'KotlinChar.Companion'`.

I suspect it appears when I added `api("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime:0.4.1")` and `export("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime:0.4.1")` in the project to use the classes of this library on iOS.

An odd thing is that the build fails only after a clean build, a consecutive one works...

I tried kotlin `1.9.10` and `1.9.20`.

Comment: sounds like a bug, I suggest you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and report it to [youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to `transitiveExport` being set to `true` causing a warning Xcode-side.

I solved it by removing the `transitiveExport` build configuration.

Here is [a project demonstrating the issue](https://gitlab.com/ryfacto/transitiveexportissue).

For more information regarding `transitiveExport` see [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-build-native-binaries.html#export-dependencies-to-binaries).